# Como reiniciar um service para chamar o oncreate novamente?

Tags: android, android-service

Eai galera,
eu tenho um service e tenho toda a lógica dele no OnCreate.
O problema é que eu preciso que ele passe pelo oncreate novamente quando eu executar uma interação na minha activity.

Já tentei fazer utilizando o

`stopService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));`

mas não deu certo. 
Alguem sabe como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

A lógica da tarefa que um Service executa não deve ser colocada no [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onCreate()).
A responsabilidade do `onCreate()` é inicializar o Serviço, nada mais.

Assim, toda essa lógica deve ser colocada no método [onStartCommand()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)), que será chamado sempre que executar `startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));`.

Comment: Ramaral, um homem muito inteligente! Gostei da resposta.